# get the value from async observable and then call service based on value angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I do have following conditions where I am waiting for one observable to finish and give me specific result before calling the service.

I have tried switchMap but there I am not able to check conditions.

```js
if (id) {
    this.initDataHTTPLoading$
        .pipe(
            debounceTime(0),
            switchMap((value) => {
                if (value === false) {
                    //i would like to call service if observable is false...
                    // return  this.service.getdata(id)
                }

            }),
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                return throwError(error);
            }),
            takeUntil(this._ngUnsubscribe$),
        )
        .subscribe(() => {});
}
```

Should I use CombineLatest?

Answer (score 1):

In else part you can return dummy observable

```
if (id) {
    this.initDataHTTPLoading$
        .pipe(
            debounceTime(0),
            switchMap((value) => {
                if (!value) {
                    return this.service.getdata(id)
                }
                return of(value)
            }),
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                return throwError(error);
            }),
            takeUntil(this._ngUnsubscribe$),
        )
        .subscribe(() => {});
}
```